# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ucanaccessDriver

Tags: jdbc, console, ucanaccess

I'm beginner with java and using console to compile and run my programs. I'm trying to read data from MS Access .accdb file with ucanaccess driver. As i have added 5 ucanaccess files to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext, but still getting Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ucanaccessDriver. 
Here is my code.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class jdbcTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:javawork/PersonInfoDB/PersonInfo.accdb";
            Connection conctn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement statmnt = conctn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM person";
            ResultSet rsltSet = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rsltSet.next())
            {
                String name = rsltSet.getString("name-");
                String address = rsltSet.getString("address");
                String phoneNum = rsltSet.getString("phoneNumber");

                System.out.println(name + " " + address + " " + phoneNum);
            }
            conctn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception sqlExcptn)
        {
            System.out.println(sqlExcptn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's wrong, you shouldn't added 5 ucanaccess jar files to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\ext but to the classpath. For more configuration informations see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UCanAccess Initializer Error (compile/run without IDE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214108/ucanaccess-initializer-error-compile-run-without-ide)

Answer (score 1):

Please add JDBC driver jar to lib folder. 
Download URL [download jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/)

Comment: Dear @dullpointer, please point to the 3.0.3 new distribution(not the old one 3.0.2)

Comment: ucanaccess 3.0.3 distribution file does not contain jdbc jar. Also i have seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc, it describes the solution only with IDEs but not with console.

Comment: The console.bat in the ucanaccess distribution may give you an advice on how to set the classpath. You absolutely don't need any different jar from five ones mentioned in the Gord's post , all needed jars are in the distribution (jdbc is java standard, not a separated jar)!

Answer (score 0):

## Upgrading to break free from vulnerabilities

In my case, the error arises after excluding `hsqldb` from `ucanaccess`, so I can use the release 2.7.2 of `hsqldb` with no security vulnerabilities. But apparently, it is not compatible with any version of `ucanaccess`, so spring fails to instantiate the `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver`.

The solution came in the form of a fork from the Source Forge project, held in GitHub: [io.github.spannm:ucanaccess](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.spannm/ucanaccess). This version 5.1.0 picks up where the original team left of (at 5.0.1 release) and is directly compatible with my code that was using the 3.0.6 release. Just changed the dependency to

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.spannm</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

and the project works again, no vulnerability from hsqldb.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the method mentioned by Gord in his post [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc) and used eclipse instead of command line compile and run. Also to learn eclipse basics, i watched video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMu-JlBrYXo.
Finally i was able to read my MS Access data base file from my java code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as to how to fix the issue.