# No Suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess:// (running from terminal)

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, ucanaccess

I am writing a program in which I access a jbdc:ucanaccess: database. When I run the program from my IDE (Netbeans) the program successfully runs.: 
Here it is ran with the IDE

[image: a]

But when I run the same program from my terminal, I get this error:
This is ran from my terminal

[image: b]

I'm also using Ubuntu, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Im not converting anything to a jar file

Comment: Okay, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34214423/2144390) is probably more to the point.

Comment: I will check it out.